# Randomly Webdriver doesn't find popover-Webelement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with retuning the text of a popover.

Case: there is a button, if i click it, there appears for 3-4 secs an popover element (before, the element isn't in the DOM and after that 3-4 secs it disappears!)

In a massive test with many repeats, in rare cases it fails an throws an TimeoutException (of course).

well my code:

```
public String getPopoverText() {
    return wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(
            new ExpectedCondition<String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(WebDriver input) {
                    return input.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.popover")).getText();
                }
            });
}
```

wait = timeout 1sec, sleepTime 200ms (error occurs with higher timeout, too)

I hope that I have the problem well brought over.
I am grateful for any help! :)

Comment: If you are just keen on getting the text verified, and not about the popup comes first or not, then you can iterate it over few times until you get the text. (ex. click the button, popup appears and disappear before getting the text, then redo the button click and try).